# Bottom App Bar slide up/down on navigating with fragments (Navigation Architecture Components)

Tags: android, material-components, android-architecture-navigation, android-bottomappbar

I was having a look at the Bottom App Bar and there is a nice feature to hide it on scroll `app:hideOnScroll="true"`. The problem it that I cannot figure it out how to slide it up or down progmatically when the fragments are being *navigated to and from*.

For example, overview of a setup: on `MainActivity` has the navigation host fragment and it is hosting a `MainFragment` and a `DetailFragment`.

The `MainFragment` has a `RecyclerView`, which on scroll, **will hide the Bottom App Bar**. On clicking any one of the item of the `RecyclerView`, it navigates to `DetailFragment`. But the problem is that the Bottom App Bar **is still hidden** and I want it to be shown.

And again, let's say that:

- the Start Destination has a `RecyclerView`; the bottom app bar is visible.
- on clicking one of the item in recycler-view, it navigates to another fragment, where it also has a recycler-view. Scroll the recycler-view and the bottom app bar slides down.
- Press the up button to get back to start destination and you will find that the bottom app bar is still hidden.

Aren't there any methods for bottom app bar to slide up or down with navigation component?

---

In `MainActivity` I'm using the following codes in order to get the Up Button, in `onCreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mBottomAppBar = findViewById(R.id.bottom_appbar);
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController);

    // ...
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    return Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigateUp();
}
```

In `activity_main.xml`, to hide the Bottom App Bar I've enabled `app:hideOnScroll="true"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    //...

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        app:hideOnScroll="true"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center|bottom" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_appbar" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Dependencies:**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-alpha06'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-alpha06'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    // ...
```

Comment: I have the same problem but with the toolbar, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `perfomShow()` method of the BottomAppBar as documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomappbar/BottomAppBar#performshow). I'm using v1.1.0 too and the method is there but I have not tested it so far. Will update this when I were able to.

Edit 1: Typo

Edit 2: The method is working: [Video](https://i.imgur.com/mMDkMY6.mp4)

Answer (score -2):

The problem has nothing to do with nav component, since it's behaving correctly. Just call `bottom_appbar.show()` along with calling your navigation code.

Comment: But there is no `show` method! The dependency is latest: `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`